# Is it OK (for a bounty) to require that answers must be tested?

Tags: discussion, bounty

More than once I've seen bounties stating "answers must be tested", with the bounty donor then commenting on answers "read the above which says test your code".

While the language is never aggressive or attacking (definitely not deserving of flagging), I do find it an incredibly rude response to someone making a genuine attempt to help.

At the same time, I know the bounty section for any given tag tends to attract low quality answers hoping for fast reputation, so maybe it's not so unreasonable.

So is it OK to expect that anyone who answers or makes suggestions should go out of their way to test the solution for you?

I'd like a definitive answer I could link to, as I was surprised to find no "Stack Overflow is not a code writing service" page exists (I had *always* thought there was such a page for some reason).

Comment: i mean.. you don't have to answer it or comply with demands. Your answer is there for both the op AND future visitors. The bounty doesn't change that.

Comment: Sure. Does not necessarily have to concern own answers though. I've seen reasonable answers deleted because of such comments. - but if I respond I'd rather know I was not in the wrong for doing so.

Comment: deleted by... who? I'd assume that's just the owner of the answer buckling under peer pressure.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I meant (and then of course, it's not available for future visitors)

Comment: this seems quite fishy... and why i hate bounties in general. The person issuing the bounty is acting like they have no interest in the question or a solution. Looks like they're wasting people's time by offering bounties on old questions.

Comment: Some users have impractically high expectations of their "investment".  It is an easy trap, they'll expect their effort in scraping together enough rep for a bounty to be returned in kind.  Quite a slog for some.  No concept of how many years you invested in knowing what you know, they haven't done that yet.  Just ignore it and post the answer you prefer.

Comment: I don't smell anything particularly fishy about requiring that answers be verifiable. I've seen enough untested, low-effort and most importantly *incorrect* answers to bounty questions that were *easily* disproved (and easily earned themselves a downvote) by simply testing their code, so these bounty messages were likely borne out of frustration with such answers (as you've postulated).

Comment: It only gets fishy when your answer *is* verifiable and you *have* tested and verified it yet the bounty setter simply chooses not to believe you. *Then* you have a right to feel shortchanged. But I've seen more bounties used for rep laundering between sock puppets than bounties withheld from answers that otherwise met their requirements.

Comment: 'OK, fine, please post your complete test specifications and how you wish to pay for this service'

Comment: Only the OP can test to ensure sufficient fitness for their own purpose.  It's unrealistic to attempt to outsource testing for free when it's overwhelmingly likely that the OP will not wish to put any effort into writing and posting test specs. harnesses, test cases, drive files, data tables etc.  That would mean, you know, actual work.

Answer (score 15):

It's unconventional to require that code in a bounty be tested...but there's nothing really to stop them from *saying* that.  At a minimum, it's a smell that there's something kinda dodgy going on.  Usually I see that as a sign that someone wants to outsource their job on to us.

It's not the most polite thing someone could say and it's best to ignore it.  If they *don't* like your answer but the rest of the community *does* and they don't pick one for themselves, it doesn't matter what requirements they put in place since the bounty will be self-awarded at the end.

Comment: To be clear, it's best to ignore it in the sense of not taking it to heart (feeling slighted, patronized, etc). Of course, there's never a reason not to test your code whether or not it's requested when it's not intended to be pseudocode.

Comment: "someone wants to outsource their job on to us" Yes, and he don't even want to test it himself.

Answer (score 6):

'Stack Overflow is not a code writing service'...

It's not a test house either.

It's not unreasonable to expect that an answering user provide code that compiles and links, maybe with minimal changes of arg names or whatever.  It IS however, unrealistic to ask them to provide any kind of testing.

Testing requires the right compiler, linker, environment, input data, output analysis.  OP's will not provide specs and data for testing, (they just won't - accept it), and even if they did, the resulting task would be far too broad, extensive and onerous for SO volunteers.

What is needed for effective testing is the same compiler, linker, environment etc. etc. as the OP has.

Only one user has that, and that user is the only one who can effectively test.

'answers must be tested' - fine, you do it!

Comment: If you write an answer that is clearly and obviously not tested against the OP's criterion, it's fair to downvote.  It's a reasonable expectation that one's answers are at least *somewhat* accurate.

Comment: Fair to downvote a broken answer; fair to post an answer without rigorously testing it; fair to **request** that "answers must be tested"; fair to ignore that request. All these things are well within bounds. Basically, _caveat lector_ when you're using SO answers.

Comment: I mean, frankly, if you expect that some stranger on the internet is going to reliably certify a bunch of code as functional and suitable for your project that they can't even see... well, I have a wonderful investment opportunity for you in [the beautiful southern United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swampland_in_Florida#Florida_swampland_scams).

Answer (score 4):

*(EDIT I've left the post as-is but see some of the conceptual refinements offered by commenters below the post.)*

Have I completely misunderstood how Stack Overflow works? (Or did I just misunderstand the question...)

I always interpreted the purpose behind

- providing an [[mcve]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),
- disallowing primarily opinion-based questions,
- [snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193323/how-to-enter-code-snippets-in-posts-on-stack-overflow)

was to *facilitate the development of high-quality answers elaborating a demonstrably workable solution*.

I don't see how a bounty is any different. To me, a bounty is simply a polite, incentivized version of an all-caps title (à la "I REALLY NEED HELP!!1!").

I have been guilty of posting a very simple code fragment without testing it, but I do so aware that I risk a flood of down-votes because I forgot a comma and it throws an exception.

Overwhelmingly, I take time, usually learning something new in the process, write some code in an IDE, compile/lint it, and post that as an answer. No, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but isn't that what MCVEs are for?

I thought the idea of "answers must be tested" was *implicit* in every question.

That said, everything about suitability for a particular purpose still applies, just because some code compiles doesn't mean it's the best (or even a good) answer.

---

Now, playing devil's advocate to myself...

I've been awarded one bounty so far for an answer on updating the Dartium VM in a custom compile of Chromium. I did a bunch of reading and answered basically "no" with references, but didn't test it.

I was interested in the problem, but just compiling Chromium without the proper environment setup can take 8+ hours. Going more in-depth was incredibly prohibitive.

I was eventually awarded (I believe, automatically) the bounty because I offered the only answer with a sufficiently positive score.

Comment: lots of bounty question posters allow themselves to post bad questions, just because they know people will do an extra effort because of the extra rep. Good questions with bounties are rare. Personally I'm staying away from them, "answers must be tested" or not.

Comment: note that nice users detecting a typo in a good answer (which hasn't been tested) won't downvote. Or will downvote with comment, wait until you fix it, then retract+upvote. If we tested all our answers (specially the ones where we know the language and the issue very well), that'd mean extra work. Sometimes it's worth taking the risk of not testing when you're sure of yourself, after all it's not _your_ problem.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes I've seen that too, or nice users will just edit and fix it. I was being slightly facetious with the "flood of downvote" (though that did happen once).

Comment: it happens when the question is bad, so the answer needs to be spot on (and tested :)) or you get rightfully slapped

Comment: I think that your sentiment on what role an MCVE plays here is a bit...off.  You're not *far* from the mark but this doesn't quite satisfy.  The MCVE is more of a mental checklist for the OP to be sure that they have all the pieces ready to go for us when we wish to assist them with their code.  The *side effect* is that the answers are high quality and that they demonstrate a workable solution.  But, there are great questions without an MCVE that have great answers.

Comment: A bounty also represents "This is a more difficult question which takes time to answer, here is an incentive to invest the time and effort to do so". It is also a way to signal "This question has answers, but they are not good enough. Please, don't ignore this question." And apparently, some people also treat them as an open contract for hire. Well... you're certainly free to try, and fail.

Comment: @Makoto Upon reflection, you're _absolutely_ right on [mcve], it is a positive side-effect rather than a primary goal.

Comment: Good point @Gimby, it is richer and more subtle than just a "polite all-caps" as I suggested.

Comment: Well also an ease of mind then: I'd find it hard to believe that you would get a rain of downvotes because you made a typo somewhere, you will get at least a comment and maybe someone will even just fix it. Now if you post an answer that is fundamentally wrong... then you'd better bring an umbrella.

Comment: To expand on Makoto's comment, MCVE doesn't apply to answers.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Really? _If the question contained one_ I find communicating the answer in an adapted form of the code is easier than in prose, even if prose will do.

Comment: Sure, if you think that's the best way to communicate your answer, then do that by all means. All I meant was that there is not a requirement that answers provide an MCVE. If a prose explanation, or prose plus a line or two of code, are better, then that's fine too.